# Not sure how to write query to fill missing observations

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a table that looks like this below:

[image]

However, I want it to look like this (where the rows in red are the missing information I want to include):
[image]

Any advice on how I can do this

Comment: You want a table with all users, all tests and all weeks, whether the user took the test or not? Generally, to fill missing values, you start with a CTE of all possible values, in your case this would be a cross join between all users, tests and weeks. Then take this CTE and left join your actual values. The result will be all possible combinations of users, tests and weeks and where you have actual values, there will be values, but where you don't have values, there will be nulls. You can take it from there.

Comment: Where will the values "-6" and "-8" come from? Is there an algorithm to fill data basde on previous weeks?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa no unfortunately those just came from my head, as MajaF. mentioned, you just need to do a cross join to get all possible combos, left join the current table we have, set nulls to 0 and then use lag to get previous values and then subtract the current from previous to get the negative values